# References to other Anime, TV shows, movies and fictional works on Steins;Gate

Tags: steins-gate

I noticed references to TV shows like `Dr.Who` in the Dub.

Also to other references to other anime like `The mail which leapt through time`.

I'd like to know all known references to other works of fiction.

Comment: If games count, in one episode Rintarou referenced Portal by saying 'That cake is a lie!'

Comment: There's a bunch of 2channel and 4chan references throughout

Comment: So how do I narrow the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dr.Who Reference by Kurisu Makise (牧瀬 紅莉栖) in the Dubbed version.

> Makise Kurisu: Safe to say String theory doesn't jive with the notion of bouncing around through time in a blue police box.

The past-altering D-mail is shortened from "Delorean Mail". Delorean is the name of the time-travelling car from the Back to the Future series. The series is mentioned by Kurisu Makise and Itaru Hashida in the game.

Various Nordic mythological terms were used as "operation names" by Rintarou Okabe.